# Ruby Zip #glob method seems to be selecting a directory. Why?

Tags: ruby, rubyzip

I'm using RubyZip to access the files inside of a Zip directory.

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(self.package.to_s) do |zipfile|
    zipfile.glob("**/*.*").each {|file| update_or_save(file)}
end
```

RubyZip has a similar #glob method to Ruby Dir#glob. From [my understanding](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/dir2.htm) of this method,

```
.glob("**/*.*")
```

Should be creating an array of all files in the subdirectories within the Zip folder. This works great for the mot part but I'm now running into an error, where a directory seems to be getting included in the array.

```
test dvd/02 Vision Seminars and TOTs/1 TOT I/TOT I Handouts/Hungary Dr. Anna handouts/
```

Why is a directory being included here? I will likely add a rescue here if need be, but I'm confused to why this directory is being added in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That directory name matches the pattern you supplied to the `#glob` method.  The pattern simply looks for a file or directory name that contains a `.` character at any level of the zip file.